# Plot response rate evolution through time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot how response rates have been evolving through a period of time on three groups. The goal is to have a graph that shows how every day response rate has changed. Something like first day we have like 5%, next day 6%, 8% and so on

The variables I have for this are: (1) the time variable called startday where every observation has assigned a date value corresponding to the day they started the survey - on the contrary non-respondents have assigned a NA value (and I do believe the problem may come from here); (2) variable non-respondent where observations are assigned to either 1 if they did not respond and 0 if they participated and (3) the variable that assigns observations to one of the three groups.

I have tried this, which has been useful to plot the distribution of other variable through time:

```
 df %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(startday)) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Rs = cumsum(`Non-respondent` %in% c(0, 1)),
         response_Rs = cumsum(sf_sex == 0)) %>% 
  group_by(date, sf_group) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(date, Rs, response_Rs, sf_group) %>% 
  mutate(response_prop = response_Rs/Rs) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = response_prop, group = sf_group, colour = sf_group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

The problem comes from the fact that I have to use the observations with NA in startday, as these all, alongside the others are the 100% of the sample and the response rate has to be computed taking into account them as well.

But the result I get is this:
[image]

Does someone know what is going wrong or another way around to compute this?

Here is a piece of my data frame:
Thank you so much for the help and your time.

```
df <-structure(list(startday = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "07/02/2019", "05/26/2019", "05/20/2019", 
                        "06/10/2019", "05/24/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, "05/25/2019", NA, 
                        NA, "05/20/2019", "05/20/2019", NA, NA, NA, "05/20/2019", "06/12/2019", 
                        NA, NA, NA, "05/30/2019", "06/10/2019", NA, "06/04/2019", "06/03/2019", 
                        NA, NA, NA, NA, "06/30/2019", "06/11/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, "05/23/2019", 
                        NA, NA, NA, "05/23/2019", "05/27/2019", "06/17/2019", "05/21/2019", 
                        "06/02/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "05/28/2019", NA, NA, 
                        "05/29/2019", "06/03/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, "05/20/2019", "06/16/2019", 
                        NA, NA, "07/08/2019", "06/16/2019", "06/24/2019", NA, NA, "05/20/2019", 
                        "05/21/2019", NA, "05/24/2019", "05/20/2019", NA, "06/14/2019", 
                        NA, NA, "05/20/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, "06/04/2019", NA, NA, "06/18/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "06/15/2019", 
                        NA, NA, "05/28/2019", "06/24/2019", NA, NA, "05/31/2019", NA, 
                        NA, "05/20/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/04/2019", NA, NA, "06/10/2019", 
                        NA, NA, "06/24/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "05/21/2019", NA, "06/14/2019", 
                        NA, "05/27/2019", "06/03/2019", NA, "05/27/2019", "05/21/2019", 
                        NA, "06/14/2019", "05/23/2019", "06/04/2019", NA, NA, "06/14/2019", 
                        NA, NA, NA, NA, "06/04/2019", "05/31/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/03/2019", 
                        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "06/19/2019", NA, "06/03/2019", NA, "05/21/2019", 
                        "05/24/2019", NA, "06/05/2019", "07/08/2019", NA, NA, "06/16/2019", 
                        "06/03/2019", NA, NA, "06/05/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/02/2019", 
                        NA, NA, NA, NA, "06/10/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Non-respondent` = c(1, 
                                                                                                    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), sf_group = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                          2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                          3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                          3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                          2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No group", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 1"
                                                                                                                                                          ), class = "factor")), row.names = c("8011", "1371", "873", "1977", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "528", "18919", "8722", "4633", "1915", "15499", "1357", "1477", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "1163", "1735", "20367", "15951", "17846", "6448", "6744", "86", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "3022", "15932", "1536", "16212", "1032", "13751", "12641", "937", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "570", "25532", "12241", "15002", "21864", "5005", "326", "22342", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "11063", "24744", "13240", "11592", "21291", "525", "18272", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "1947", "10319", "1561", "9809", "5181", "6811", "6465", "440", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "6737", "10780", "13631", "13503", "1884", "17231", "8941", "633", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "8624", "8378", "77", "134", "17033", "12024", "10251", "19967", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "6102", "2007", "13108", "8254", "11576", "382", "18078", "8542", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "1889", "18932", "3093", "8693", "21749", "9271", "1240", "63", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "20334", "2907", "15081", "9867", "17560", "14360", "965", "5082", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "20037", "5622", "24726", "998", "18748", "1269", "1577", "980", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "84", "11064", "14970", "20121", "11046", "1738", "25514", "1876", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "1036", "8711", "7266", "4320", "10040", "9780", "5503", "3247", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "2055", "17981", "2272", "4479", "23322", "6361", "623", "22411", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "9620", "20939", "20002", "6493", "19896", "21975", "20692", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "17702", "23389", "278", "15974", "19556", "603", "744", "15689", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "12927", "1724", "13334", "6966", "986", "12082", "22650", "266", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "16610", "6475", "39", "17807", "19787", "193", "6544", "15671", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "4101", "1658", "2471", "2487", "723", "10298", "15988", "18664", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "6571", "16745", "11901", "4639", "3981", "9126", "24546", "20912", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "3362", "674", "1823", "7887", "767", "13939", "20856", "10735", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "10176", "377", "2037", "4718", "11495", "18804", "4617", "12646", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "19256", "7050", "2566", "13527", "2141", "1607", "301", "422", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "5560", "5868", "1401", "1995", "5782", "9172"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making life too complicated.  Since all rows with missing `startday` also have `Non-respondent` equal to `1`, the simplest approach is to sort your dataset by descending `Responder` (to avoid the confusing double negative and awkward back-ticks) and ascending date.  Then the proportion of responders at any given date is simply the row number divided by the total number of rows in the data frame.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    StartDate=mdy(startday),
    Responder=!`Non-respondent`
  ) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Responder), StartDate) %>% 
  mutate(Prop=row_number()/nrow(.)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=StartDate, y=Prop, group=sf_group, colour=sf_group)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

```
packageVersion("tidyverse")
[1] ‘1.3.1’
packageVersion("lubridate")
[1] ‘1.7.10’
```

***Revised Edit***

In response to OP's clarification that they want the proportions calculated *within group*, not overall.  This is straightforward.
Note that grouped data doesn't have to be sorted by the grouping variable(s).

The confusion discussed in the comments below is the perfect example of why a well crafted question of this type should include at least some indication of the expected output.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    StartDate=mdy(startday),
    Responder=!`Non-respondent`
  ) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Responder), StartDate) %>% 
  group_by(sf_group) %>% 
  mutate(Prop=1:length(cur_group_rows())/n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=StartDate, y=Prop, colour=sf_group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Check that the graph has at least credible properties:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    StartDate=mdy(startday),
    Responder=!`Non-respondent`
  ) %>% 
  group_by(sf_group, Responder) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop") %>%  
  pivot_wider(values_from=N, names_from=Responder) %>% 
  mutate(Pct=`TRUE` / (`TRUE` + `FALSE`))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  sf_group `FALSE` `TRUE`   Pct
  <fct>      <int>  <int> <dbl>
1 No group      86     52 0.377
2 Groupe 2      18     13 0.419
3 Groupe 1      23      8 0.258
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like what I want but I cannot check it on my data. When using your code I get an error telling me that mdy function cannot be found, yet, I am using the mdy function for the code I posted here. Do you know what is going on? 

It is going to be a novice error most likely...

Comment: You don't have `lubridate` loaded. try writing `lubridate::mdy`

Comment: @MarcAsensioManjon: the reason you don't get the same error with your code is that you specify the package with `lubridate::` when calling `mdy()`.  That means you don't have to load the package explicitly.  I didn't use `lubridate::`, so I do need to load it explicitly.

Comment: I see. Honestly I could have noticed that, my bad. In any case, now I get this error:
Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
Backtrace:
  1. plyr::mutate(., StartDate = lubridate::mdy(startday), Responder = !`Non-respondent`)
  1. plyr::arrange(., desc(Responder), StartDate)
  8. plyr::mutate(., Prop = row_number()/nrow(.))
  9. [ base::eval(...) ] with 1 more call
 11. dplyr::row_number()
 12. dplyr::n()
 13. dplyr:::peek_mask("n()")
 14. dplyr:::context_peek("mask", fun)

Is this a clash of packages?

Comment: It could be.  Or a difference in versions.  Try restarting R and then running my code in a fresh session. It should work: there's nothing fancy in it.  I'll post my package versions in an edit.  Then you can see if that's the issue.

Comment: I had a package colliding most likely. Now I do get your results. Nonethless, there is something wrong with the agrupation by sf_group; as it is not really creating three diferent lines but it simply takes the line of the graph without distinction by group and coloring it. I cannot attach the graph in a comment so it is hard to explain.

Comment: Ah!  That changes the question.  I though you wanted to calculatethe proportion of responses across *all participants*.  Not *within groups*.  That means calculating the N's within group (not as simply the row count of the entire data frame).  The change is simple.  Wait whilst I update...

Comment: I am sorry, I should made the point clear on the OP. However, looking at the graph I got thanks to your code, the response rates are 29%, 4% and 4%, which sum 37% in total (and that is the response rate of the whole sample). But I should be getting something like 39% for no group, 31% for groupe 1 and 29% for groupe 2. This is, the response rate based exclusively on that group. Gosh I am sorry, I feel I did not explained it right?